# Can a server page (jsp, aspx) be used as Web Service

Tags: web-services

What is the difference between using a "Web Service" and calling a server page such as JSP/ASPX?

To me it looks like a Web Service is just a framework around the server pages. For e.g. I can have a JSP page that takes:

mypage.jsp?method=getupdate&param1=23&param=44
(I can also send these variables through POST)

In my JSP page I can call the appropriate method based on the value of "method" and return a value back to the caller client app. Is this the raw form how a Web Service actually works? OR is there more to a Web Service call like someone told me that when you call a page, it is rendered but a Web Service is not rendered. But What if I remove the HTML code from JSP page then?

So when we say XML Web Service, the difference is that the client and the server both wrap/unwrap the requests/responses using XML and POST it to the Web Service page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Services are a well defined [set of standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-arch/) [defined by the W3C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) and other relevant bodies,  which mostly define an architecture that runs over a network to communicate diverse applications while ensuring interoperability, discoverability and some other relevant criteria.

You can certainly create a server page just for your application without SOAP or XML-RPC. It's just that you shouldn't call it a "Web Service" unless it outputs SOAP or XML-RPC and provides a WSDL description for itself, because that leads to confusion and show you don't know what the "standard Web Services" mean.

Comment: I wont call the page as a Web Service because the word "Web Service" does not signify a single server page but a whole set of classes, resources, pages and more. Also, will there be a difference if any in the execution of a server page and a Web Service?

Comment: A Web Service could be a single page as well. It's just that if you invent your own protocol that's not listed in Web Services specs, you shouldn't call it a web service. Execution-wise there is no necessary difference, it's just code, only that instead of outputting HTML, it outputs SOAP or XML-RPC (XML).

Comment: How do REST web services fit in you definition of having to 'output SOAP or XML-RPC' and provide a WSDL?  I'm not even sure what you mean by 'outputing' xml-rpc.

Comment: It should say "outputs SOAP or XML-RPC messages" instead, sorry. What I mean is that the response instead of containing HTML, contains XML describing a remote procedure call message. I personally think that "REST web service" is a misnomer. You can implement web services (in the WS-* standards sense) using the REST architecture or choose not to. But I feel this is a lost battle, just like 'cracker' v/s 'hacker'.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to say that web services are a layer on top of the server pages. One of the common types of web services are [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) web services that wrap requests and response into XML to achieve interoperability between different platforms/frameworks.

Comment: So if I have want to have a Web Service for "just" my application written in some language, I dont need to use SOAP or any other protocol. I can have my own format of data and my own way of calling the methods.

Comment: You can certainly do that, but in this case you shouldn't call your page a Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

Sites like Facebook and Flickr that have much the same kind of public APIs are calling them 'web services' and I don't see that you're doing anything different.

Vinko seems to have some objection to polluting the 'Web Service' moniker but there's plenty of room under the W3 definition of a web service to include what you're doing.

As for Web services having to output SOAP or XML and provide a WSDL? I think there's a few REST advocates that would argue that point.

Comment: You can implement discoverability and use in a REST-style architecture, or not. The problem I personally have with calling EVERY KIND of API that receives parameters and returns responses (in any format whatsoever) a web service is that it dillutes the meaning effectively making it meaningless. [Continues...]

Comment: Before I could be sure that if my app would communicate with some other app using Web Services I would barely need the other app devs support. I'd simply grab the WDSL and call the appropriate (documented) methods, receiving any kind of (potentially complex) response. Now, when everything is a 'web service', I have to wait for their documentation and see if it is a 'real' web service, or just some cooked up API where I have to implement an ad-hoc parser and see what structures do they return and implement specific response parsing code for each different API.